# Custom font doesn't have a line wrap

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I use custom font, it will cover other text instead of auto linefeed.

How to make it auto linefeed?

[image]

[image]

solution [image]

Comment: No codes. Just unity3d Text component.

Comment: How did you create the custom font?

Comment: Create->Custom Font. Use bitmap font with a png and a fnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find this tutorial useful:

[Tutorial][Unity] Generate and import a bitmap font with a free tool -

http://www.benoitfreslon.com/unity-generate-and-import-a-bitmap-font-with-a-free-tool

In addition, follow the help for line spacing:

> You can change the spacing or the kerning if you create a editable
>   copy of the font, you just have to click in the font (in the Assets
>   panel), go to the gear icon of the Inspector panel and click "Create
>   Editable Copy". The new copy on the Assets panel has a parameter
>   called "Line Spacing" that you can modify at will.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22732/how-can-i-adjust-line-spacing-for-a-font.html

Comment: Thanks. The "Kerning" default value is "1", "Line Spacing" is "0.1", look at the picture on my question. I change them to very large, doesn't work. What they should be?

Comment: Found solution : change the text component's "Line Spacing" to very large like "300".

Answer (score 0):

So, for those of you who created your custom font in much smaller pixels (e.g., 7x7), try changing the Line Spacing to one number above the width/height. If each letter is about 8x8, change the Line Spacing to 9 and adjust from there.